# how can i access directly to magento order history from observer?

Tags: magento

How can i get the value ,what i set by addStatusHistoryComment while creating order by php script.

```
                    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
                    $dbOrderId = $order->getId();
                    $MagOrderId = $order->getRealOrderId();
                    Mage::log('dbOrderId : '. $dbOrderId);
                    Mage::log('MagOrderId : '. $MagOrderId);
```

I need to get like something  $order->getStatusHistoryComment()
it is not working.

Need help.

The following data is not working as order is not commit yet.

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

$sql = "SELECT comment FROM sales_flat_order_status_history WHERE  parent_id=' $dbOrderId' limit 1 ";
        $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        foreach ($connection->fetchAll($sql) as $arr_row) {
        $comments=$arr_row['comment'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getStatusHistoryCollection` instead of `getStatusHistoryComment` and it should work. The method is defined in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`.
Or you can use `getVisibleStatusHistory` if you want only the comments visible on frontend.

Comment: think this is not yet commit. in this case does it works? $order->getStatusHistoryComment (); so you think it will work for me.